# Android steps counter sensor is updated only if application is in focus on some devices

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-background, sensormanager

I'm developing steps counter application on Android.
To get the steps the application is listening to onSensorChanged(..) event of **Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER** sensor.

*The problem is* that on some devices application is not in focus the device counter is not incremented at all. But if application is in focus it counts pretty accurate. On other devices it works well in both modes. The problematic device is Samsung note 8 (Android 9). The strange thing, that it worked fine before I restarted the phone. Samsung Health steps counter works fine.

**Expected**:
step counter is incremented w/o relation to application state

**Actual**:
step counter is incremented only if application is in focus

> in **onResume** method I register the listener.

```
    SensorManager sensorManager =
                (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(mListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, 0);
```

> This is the listener.

```
private final SensorEventListener mListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        mCounterSteps = (int) event.values[0];            
        if(stepsTextView != null)   stepsTextView.setText("" + mCounterSteps);
    }               
            
     @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) { }
};
```